# How to tell what interface a TCP connection will go out on?

Tags: networking, routing

I have a server with multiple ethernet interfaces.  What's the easiest way to tell what interface an outgoing TCP connection will go out over?  The results of "netstat -rn" is greek to me, so if your answer is "look at the local routing table", please be detailed and clear.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For me I can see what interface I have right there using the `netstat -rn` or `route -n`

```
cyrex@cyrex:~$ netstat -nr
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
0.0.0.0         192.48.0.1      0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 eth0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U         0 0          0 eth0
192.48.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.224.0   U         0 0          0 eth0
```

Or `netstat -r`

```
cyrex@cyrex:~$ netstat -r
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
default         192-48-0-1.dyn. 0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 eth0
link-local      *               255.255.0.0     U         0 0          0 eth0
192.48.0.0      *               255.255.224.0   U         0 0          0 eth0
```

In both cases I can see the name of the interface at the end, in this case it is **eth0**

The information given by this commands is as followed (Source found [here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/what-is-a-routing-table/)):

**Destination** - The destination network or destination host.

**Gateway** - The gateway address or `*` if none set.

**Genmask** - The netmask for the destination net.

```
 255.255.255.255 for the host destination.
 0.0.0.0 for the default route.
```

**Flags** - Possible flags include:

```
 U (route is up)  
 H (target is a host)  
 G (using gateway)  
 R (reinstate route for dynamic routing)  
 D (dynamically installed by daemon or redirect)  
 M (modified from routing daemon or redirect)  
 A (installed by addrconf)  
 C (cache entry)  
 ! (reject route)
```

**MSS** - Default maximum segment size for TCP connections over this route.

**Window** - Default window size for TCP connections over this route.

**irtt** - Initial RTT (Round Trip Time). The kernel uses this to guess about the best TCP protocol parameters without waiting on (possibly slow) answers.

**Iface** - Interface to which packets for this route will be sent.

Other fields can be:

**Metric** - The distance to the target (usually counted in hops). It is not used by recent kernels, but may be needed by routing daemons.

**Ref** - Number of references to this route. (Not used in the Linux kernel.)

**Use** - Count of lookups for the route. Depending on the use of -F and -C this will be either route cache misses (-F) or hits (-C).

**HH** (cached only) - The number of ARP entries and cached routes that refer to the hardware header cache for the cached route. This will be -1 if a hardware address is not needed for the interface of the cached route (e.g. lo).

**Arp** (cached only) - Whether or not the hardware address for the cached route is up to date.

Now to the question at hand. The easiest way I can remember right now (As always, there are several ways of doing the same thing) is by using `iptraf`. Just install it:

`sudo apt-get install iptraf`

and run it with root priveleges: `sudo iptraf`

In the menu of `iptraf` select **IP Traffic Monitor** and then choose **All Interfaces**. That should show you all TCP connections and to which interface they are related to. It is terminal based which is good for monitoring purposes.

Comment: Nice answer Luis. You can also use the command `route`

Comment: Rather than say go look and see where it *does* go, the correct answer should say given this routing table information, you can see where traffic for a given address *will* go.

Answer (score 10):

You can query the kernel routing tables using the `ip` command. Its `route get` subcommand will tell you exactly how the kernel will route a packet to a destination address:

```
 $ ip route get to 10.0.2.2
 10.0.2.2 dev eth0  src 10.0.2.15
```

whereas

```
$ ip route get to 192.168.3.5
192.168.3.5 via 10.0.2.2 dev eth0  src 10.0.2.15
```

and

```
$ ip route get to 127.0.1.1
local 127.0.1.1 dev lo  src 127.0.0.1
```